# Ionic build failed "unexpected element <provider> found in <manifest>"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have this code

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="nl.x-services.plugins.videocaptureplus.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

But if i try "Ionic cordova run android" i have this error

https://pastebin.com/BAtL0VqK

What can I do with this error?

Comment: Anyone found solution on it

Answer (score 5):

The issue seems to be with VideoCapturePlus as I was getting the same problem.  I have swapped it for MediaCapture and no longer have this problem.

Comment: MediaCapture not supporting duration option.

Answer (score 4):

There is indeed a `<provider>` element wrongly injected in the resulting `AndroidManifest.xml`.
This element comes from the `plugin.xml` file of the videoCapturePlus plugin.

1. **comment out the faulty lines** in file `/node_modules/cordova-plugin-video-capture-plus/plugin.xml`

   ```
        <provider
                android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="nl.x-services.plugins.videocaptureplus.provider"
                android:exported="false"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
   ```
2. **re-generate the platform files** (android) using command-line

`ionic cordoba build android` or `ionic capacitor build android`

3. **re-run the gradle build** in android studio

That's it !

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove this [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAtgb.png) from plugin/nl.x-services.plugins.videocaptureplus/plugin.xml

Answer (score 0):

I fix editing platform/android/android.json

move the block

[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux5Pt.png)
into "Application" block
[step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pudxP.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is the sequence I did

```
npx cordova platform rm android --nosave
npx ionic cordova plugin rm nl.x-services.plugins.videocaptureplus
npx ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/Neocrea/cordova-plugin-video-capture-plus\#patch-1
npx ionic cordova platform add android@latest
```

I used [https://github.com/Neocrea/cordova-plugin-video-capture-plus\#patch-1](https://github.com/Neocrea/cordova-plugin-video-capture-plus%5C#patch-1) because it had the requisite patch that fixes the issue.  It's not the best solution IMO, instead you should be using [media capture](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media-capture/) plugin instead which is something we are migrating to, but this is a stop gap.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue and working perfectly in my case on android, just follow the steps:

1. In file **platforms\android\android.json**
2. Remove below code inside array **"AndroidManifest.xml": {
   "parents": {
   "/manifest/application": [** **"/*": [ .... ]**

> {
> "xml": "<provider android:authorities="nl.x-services.plugins.videocaptureplus.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"><meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />",
> "count": 1
> }

3. And put the code in **"application"** array

[image]

and make build again : **ionic cordoba build android** (Command line) and in android studio, re-run the gradle build