# ionic cordova build android problem while using MediaCapture

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic 5.4.6 and with cordova 9.0.0 to build a very simple android application which allows to take a video. I'm using the following typeSctrip code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MediaCapture, MediaFile, CaptureError } from '@ionic-native/media-capture/ngx';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
   constructor(private mediaCapture: MediaCapture) {}
   onTakeVideo(){
      this.mediaCapture.captureImage({ limit: 3 }).then(
         (data: MediaFile[]) => console.log(data),
         (err: CaptureError) => console.error(err)
      );
   }
}
```

When I try to build an android project using the command "ionic cordova build android" I'm having the following error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  D:\WebDev\TPs\Ionic\video-record\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:29: AAPT: error: unexpected element <provider> found in <manifest>.

  D:\WebDev\TPs\Ionic\video-record\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:38: AAPT: error: unexpected element <provider> found in <manifest>.

  D:\WebDev\TPs\Ionic\video-record\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:47: AAPT: error: unexpected element <provider> found in <manifest>.

  D:\WebDev\TPs\Ionic\video-record\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:56: AAPT: error: unexpected element <provider> found in <manifest>.

  D:\WebDev\TPs\Ionic\video-record\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:65: AAPT: error: unexpected element <provider> found in <manifest>.
```

I found a similar situation in:
[Ionic build failed "unexpected element <provider> found in <manifest>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044182/ionic-build-failed-unexpected-element-provider-found-in-manifest)
but no one of the suggested solutions worked with me. Any new suggestions? Thanks in advence.

Comment: The problem in android manifest.xml, reach the folder and search for provider that i think it should be added multiple times or at least added and it should not be added at manifest so try to remove it.